# Thermocouple + Instrumentation amplifier. Does it make sense to have one input grounded?

Tags: operational-amplifier, grounding, instrumentation-amplifier, thermocouple

[image]

I am trying to read a thermocouple (of an existing assembly) and half way into the project I noticed that one pin is grounded (protective earth). Makes no sense to use an inamp this way, does it? Instead I could use a very low pA bias current single op-amp in negative feedback configuration ...

Or are there any problems with that? I could also try to create a floating ground for the inamp or isolate the heater assembly from PE ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are reading a thermocouple, it might be reverse wired so as to produce a negative voltage rather than a positive voltage that could be resolved by a single-rail op-amp.

I would still use an InAmp (because of this) and I would ensure that it operates on +/- 5 volt rails to provide sufficient headroom to avoid input common-mode range issues.